# How do I use ajax to post XML data to the server?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is exactly the data I want to pass to the server:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"
xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
<Placemark>
  <name>model1</name>
  <Model id="model_1">
    <Location>
      <longitude>-5.986926473546048</longitude>
      <latitude>37.37725475811571</latitude>
      <altitude>0</altitude>
    </Location>
    <Orientation>
      <heading>0</heading>
      <tilt>0</tilt>
      <roll>0</roll>
    </Orientation>
    <Scale>
      <x>1</x>
      <y>1</y>
      <z>1</z>
    </Scale>
    <Link>
      <href>http://www.ihs.org/objects/streetlight.dae</href>
    </Link>
    <ResourceMap>
      <Alias>
        <targetHref>http://www.ihs.org/objects/streetlight/texture0.jpg</targetHref>
        <sourceHref>streetlight/texture0.jpg</sourceHref>
      </Alias>
      <Alias>
        <targetHref>http://www.ihs.org/objects/streetlight/texture1.jpg</targetHref>
        <sourceHref>streetlight/texture1.jpg</sourceHref>
      </Alias>
    </ResourceMap>
  </Model>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
  <name>model2</name>
  <Model id="model_2">
    <Location>
      <longitude>-5.986969267031843</longitude>
      <latitude>37.37727640316665</latitude>
      <altitude>0</altitude>
    </Location>
    <Orientation>
      <heading>0</heading>
      <tilt>0</tilt>
      <roll>0</roll>
    </Orientation>
    <Scale>
      <x>1</x>
      <y>1</y>
      <z>1</z>
    </Scale>
    <Link>
      <href>http://www.ihs.org/objects/streetlight.dae</href>
    </Link>
    <ResourceMap>
      <Alias>
        <targetHref>http://www.ihs.org/objects/streetlight/texture0.jpg</targetHref>
        <sourceHref>streetlight/texture0.jpg</sourceHref>
      </Alias>
      <Alias>
        <targetHref>http://www.ihs.org/objects/streetlight/texture1.jpg</targetHref>
        <sourceHref>streetlight/texture1.jpg</sourceHref>
      </Alias>
    </ResourceMap>
  </Model>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

I'm sending that this through an ajax post, thus,

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:"/php/sendEdition.php?kml="+output,
                    async: true,
                    success: function(datos){
                        //datakml = eval(datos);
                        document.getElementById('dataOut').innerHTML = datos;                          

            },
                   error: function (obj, error, objError){

                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
```

This is not working. No data is being sent to the server. I think that perhaps you cannot just pass HTML tags through ajax; is that right? I’m not using a form but that’s okay because I already got all the information.

Comment: "I'm having a problem" - what is the problem? You left out the most important thing.

Comment: Just going to throw it out there - Don't use `mysql_` functions as they are deprecated; use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead =)

Comment: @Timmy, no, the main problem is that nothing arrives to the php page, I know there are some tricks to pass data through url, my question is because I dont really think you can send html labels in a url. I'm pretty new with all this stuff, so I'll be glad if anyone can tell me.

Comment: @karoly Horvath, explain what I forgot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
type: "POST",
url:"/php/sendEdition.php?kml="+output+",
```

First, that quotation mark at the end, before the comma, is a syntax error. Remove it.

Second, you are appending the data to the URL, which will produce a URL like `/php/sendEdition.php?kml=<?xml version="1.0"` .... You can immediately see a problem here, in that question marks and ampersands (and other values) in the XML data should be URL escaped, but aren’t.

You could fix this by using `encodeURIComponent()`, thus:

```
type: "POST",
url: "/php/sendEdition.php?kml=" + encodeURIComponent(output),
```

Now your XML will be properly escaped.

However, why are you sending your XML in the URL at all? This is a POST request, with a POST body. Large data is better sent that way.

```
type: "POST",
url: "/php/sendEdition.php",
data: {"kml": output},
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to store a pointer to a file into the database which is not possible. Instead you should store the contents of the file into the database.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO places_edited (id_user, user_name, user_pic_square, id_place, place_name, place_pic, latitude, longitude, kml, place_type, description)
VALUES ('$id_user', '$user_name', '$user_pic_square', '$id_place', '$place_name', '$place_pic', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$kml', '$place_type', '$description')");
```

You could also create a temporary file and store the filename, but the first option is easier.

Comment: ups! sorry! That was just a crazy try! I'll edit the question, the problem is exactly that the data of the kml, is not yet a file, is a variable wich I'm trying to pass and for some reason doesn't arrive to the php

Comment: then where does output come from?

Comment: the kml script, the variable output is all the kml script that is in the middle of the question. The thing is that I don't know if is possible to pass all that data through the post command, well confirmed is not passing it, it's empty in php

Answer (score 0):

You're using `type: "POST"` in your ajax call and then trying to access it using `GET` in your PHP code.

Change your PHP `$_GET` superglobals to `$_POST` instead like so:-

```
$id_user=$_POST['id_user'];
$user_name=$_POST['user_name'];
$user_pic_square=$_POST['user_pic_square'];
$id_place=$_POST['id_place'];
$place_name=$_POST['place_name'];
$place_pic=$_POST['place_pic'];
$latitude=$_POST['latitude'];
$longitude=$_POST['longitude'];
$kml=$_POST['kml'];               //THIS ONE IS THE BLOB FIELD
$place_type=$_POST['place_type'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
```

etc

Hope this helps.

Also, take a look at the PHP documentation - `mysql_` functions are no longer used, use `mysqli_` instead or PDO instead. This isn't your problem, just a suggestion.

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/) offers a nice starting point for PHP and MySQL tutorials.

Comment: nop, changing the type didn't appears to do anything. I do believe is the amount of data of the output(kml) variable, probablly is because is received in php as a html page or something like this...

Comment: No, it won't - I'm not sure how to go about helping you here but you are trying to pass an XML form to PHP via ajax. Your PHP code is looking for variables posted via the ajax code which are not posted. Take a look at PHP form handling, it won't help your immediate problem but will help you to understand why no data is actually showing up :)

Comment: I have checked all at this moment, probablly you have described better my issue "pass an XML form to PHP vía Ajax", that's what I'm trying but no info on the web!!

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

```
$.ajax({
                        type     : "POST",
                        url      : "/php/uploadkml.php?",
                        data     : { "kml": encodeURIComponent(output) },
                        //dataType : "xml",
                        success  : function(datos){
                            document.getElementById('dataOut').innerHTML = datos;
                        alert("Success");
                        },
                        error    : function(datos) {
                            if (datos){
                            datakml = eval(datos);
                            document.getElementById('dataOut').innerHTML = datakml;
                            }
                        alert("Failed");
                        }
                    });
```

And decode it at the php.

There were many other options but I don't understand why this one was the only one for me...